# Razorpay payment gateway in flutter mobile app

Tags: flutter, payment-gateway, mobile-application, razorpay

I am trying to integrate Razorpay into my mobile app. I understand the implementation and am able to generate/complete test payments from my app. Now when I read [here](https://razorpay.com/docs/payments/payment-gateway/flutter-integration/standard/build-integration/#110-verify-payment-signature) about the authorization of payment I am a bit confused about it, what I should or need to save in server (apart from paymentId,orderId and signature)for future reference. I can see a tab transaction in the Razorpay dashboard which is showing me the status of payment(authorized/failed) then what is the use of this part. How can I use webhook for authorization?
Anyone who has implemented it please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

1. install `flutter pub add razorpay_flutter` [pubdev](https://pub.dev/packages/razorpay_flutter)
2. `import 'package:razorpay_flutter/razorpay_flutter.dart';`
3. create a instance of Razorpay by `_razorpay = Razorpay();`

it uses event-based communication and emits events like

- EVENT_PAYMENT_SUCCESS
- EVENT_PAYMENT_ERROR
- EVENT_EXTERNAL_WALLET

so we have to listen to these events with respective functions to handle the payments.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _razorpay = Razorpay();

    _razorpay.on(Razorpay.EVENT_PAYMENT_SUCCESS, _handlePaymentSuccess);
    _razorpay.on(Razorpay.EVENT_PAYMENT_ERROR, _handlePaymentError);
    _razorpay.on(Razorpay.EVENT_EXTERNAL_WALLET, _handleExternalWallet);
  }

  void _handlePaymentSuccess(PaymentSuccessResponse response) {

    var orderId = response.orderId;
    var signature = response.signature;
    var paymentId = response.paymentId;
    
    //Do your stuff

}

 void _handlePaymentError(PaymentFailureResponse response) {
     var code= response.code;
     var message = response.message ;
  }

 void _handleExternalWallet(ExternalWalletResponse response) {
 
  }


 void openCheckout() {
       //create a Map which details 

       var options = {

      "key": "Use Your API Key Id here",
      "amount":amount, 
      "name": "test",
      "description": "Test Payment",
      "order_id": orderId.toString(),
      "timeout": "60",
      "theme.color": "#5eba7d",
      "currency": "INR",
      "prefill": {"contact": "546338833332", "email": "test@testing.com"},
     
    };
    try {
      _razorpay.open(options);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

in any click call `openCheckout();` this function

at last, dispose of it

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _razorpay.clear();
  }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but i have already implemented this . I want to know what else we need to do server side or app side like if payment is autorized or valid..